# How can I include an enum in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, enums

I have a helper class in which I have a function with parameters. A parameter of type string can only have three values: 'status_a', 'status_b', 'status_c'. Currently I validate the status with an in_array(). In an interesting exchange on Stackoverflow it was mentioned that you can also use an enum for validation.

I have created an Enums folder and put my enum file in it:

```php
<?php
// app/Enums/StatusTypes.php
namespace App\Enums;

enum StatusTypes: string
{
    case status_a = 'status_a';
    case status_b = 'status_b';
    case status_c = 'status_c';
}
```

In my helper class I would now like to have access to the enum file. But I don't know how to get access to it. Since it is not a class, I cannot extend it. Also PHPStorm does not recognize the file `Undefined Class StatusTypes` when I want to get it into my helper class with `use App\Enums\StatusTypes;`. Because it is not a class!

Thanks for your help!

```php
<?php
// app/Helpers/SomeHelperClass.php
namespace App\Helper;

use App\Enums\StatusTypes;

class SomeHelperClass
{

    private $allowedStatusTypes = ['status_a','status_b','status_c'];

    public function some_method(string $status): array
    {
        if (! in_array($status, $this->allowedStatusTypes)) {
            return [];
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `Stypes != StatusTypes`

Comment: Ignoring the PHPStorm issues, does code using this enum work? If the issue is only in PHPStorm then maybe it has not detected the composer.json file correctly

Comment: @apokryfos Unfortunately not. when i start my tests then it thown: `Error: Class "App\Enums\IntlFormatterTypes" not found`

Comment: @MartinTTS And are you running the correct PHP version (`>=8.1` I think)?

Comment: @matronator i running in my docker 8.2.5 and local 8.2.14. thanks for your question

Comment: `IntlFormatterTypes` is not the same enum you shared here. Make sure you have correctly placed that in `app/Enums` and named that `IntlFormatterTypes.php` (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `use` statement to import the enum should work:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Helper;

use App\Enums\StatusTypes;

class SomeHelperClass
{
    public function some_method(string $status)
    {
        if (StatusTypes::tryFrom($status) !== null) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have autoloading set-up correctly?

Comment: `Do you have autoloading set-up correctly?` Do you mean: `composer autoload dump`?

Comment: To check if there is a string case in the enum you can check `if (StatusTypes::tryFrom($status) !== null)`

Comment: @MartinTTS I mean in general, like if you have it properly set in `composer.json` so that your enums folder is loaded correctly. Also, the correct command is `composer dump-autoload` which might not be a bad idea to try if you're not using PSR-4. Since you created the enums folder, you might have to run that command again to update the classes to include your enums.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, I couldn't remember how to check if a string is a valid enum case, but I figured `instanceof` would do the trick like it does in TypeScript. Do you know if there is any difference between the two or which is better to use? (Assuming the `instanceof` method works correctly, I haven't tested it)

Comment: @matronator if i could get it to work i would be able to query the enum instance with `->value`.

Comment: @matronator I don't think the same works in PHP directly. `StatusTypes::tryFrom($status) instanceof StatusTypes` might work, but in general you need to convert the string to the enum before checking